# Java : why missing "new" operator while instantiating an object?

Tags: java, android

Below is a method of demo code on JavaDeveloper website.

I have a quick and simple question: On the third line, the code is ...

```
final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.list_item_example, mContainerView, false);
```

It has been told that when instantiating an object, there should be a "new" operator. Why isn't there a "new" operator for the "newView" ? And when I tried to add a "new" after "=" sign, Android Studio showed "not a statement" error.

```
private void addItem() {
    // Instantiate a new "row" view.
    final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.list_item_example, mContainerView, false);

    // Set the text in the new row to a random country.
    ((TextView) newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
            COUNTRIES[(int) (Math.random() * COUNTRIES.length)]);

    // Set a click listener for the "X" button in the row that will remove the row.
    newView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Remove the row from its parent (the container view).
            // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
            // this removal is automatically animated.
            mContainerView.removeView(newView);

            // If there are no rows remaining, show the empty view.
            if (mContainerView.getChildCount() == 0) {
                findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
    // adding this view is automatically animated.
    mContainerView.addView(newView, 0);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Bloch's "Effective Java". He explains how developers can create objects in the beginning of his book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling a method that, somewhere in its implementation, uses `new` already.  This is called a factory method, and it's a very widespread practice in Java -- for good reason.

For example, think of the following method:

```
Foo createFoo() {
  return new Foo();
}
```

...you could just call `createFoo()`, without writing `new` yourself, and inside its implementation it will generate the new object.  That's what's happening here.

Answer (score 5):

Because the Inflater itself is creating the object-  its returning a `new View()`.  ANy time an object is returned from a function it must already have been instantiated, so new is not needed.

Comment: Very useful answer. @Gabe Sechan